# I can't locate my pid file to delete it so that I can start postgresql again?

Tags: postgresql

Long story short my db didn't get shutdown correctly and I am trying to get it back up and running

I have run a

```
sudo find / -name postmaster.pid
```

to locate the file.
but when I run

```
sudo rm /Users/cward/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-10/postmaster.pid
```

I get the following

```
rm: /Users/cward/Library/Application: No such file or directory
rm: Support/Postgres/var-10/postmaster.pid: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your folder name contain space. You should quote the full path like this:

```
sudo rm "/Users/cward/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-10/postmaster.pid"
```

Comment: Jeez where can I hide. Thank you!